# Dynamically incresing the size of 2d array row elements

Tags: c

I have a 2d array of integers. Initially, the rows are empty as I am trying to not allocate any additional memory to them if it's not required.

```
int** resultIndexArr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n + 8);
int arrayItemsLastIndex[] = {0,0};
int lastAnswer = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < queries_rows; i++) {
    int type = *(*(queries + i));
    int x = *(*(queries + i) + 1);
    int y = *(*(queries + i) + 2);
    
    if(type == 1 ) {
        int idx = ((x ^ lastAnswer) % n);
        resultIndexArr[idx] = realloc(resultIndexArr[idx], sizeof(int) * (arrayItemsLastIndex[idx] + 1));
        resultIndexArr[idx][arrayItemsLastIndex[idx]] = y;
        printf("%d \n", idx); //output: 0
        print("%d \n", arrayItemsLastIndex[idx]); //output: 0
        printf("%d \n", resultIndexArr[idx][arrayItemsLastIndex[idx]]); //output: y
        arrayItemsLastIndex[idx]++;
                    
    }
    printf("%d \n", resultIndexArr[0][0]); // garbage value }
```

**Note: I am new to c**

I am trying to allocate new memory while keeping the values of the row using realloc.
You can say it's like pushing to an array in simple words.

What I am trying to do is just increase the size of a row in a 2d array without losing its values.

Comment: `arrayItemsLastIndex[]` is only 2 elements long. Perhaps you should allocate that dynamically too.

Comment: ... and it's not clear from your code what `n` is (as used in the remainder operator).

Comment: .. or perhaps `arrayItemsLastIndex[]` is supposed to store the last index in each of the two dimensions? But `arrayItemsLastIndex[idx]` will be out of bounds when `idx` is greater than 1.

Comment: @AdrianMole n is integer 2

Comment: `resultArrIndex` contents will be junk initially. Calling `realloc` on a junk pointer leads to UB. You should set the elements of `resultArrIndex` to `NULL`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you setting the elements to NULL did the job